# Synchronous request in Node.js with async.retry

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

**nodejs version v10.14.2
OS win7 sp1 64bit**

**I need the following four lines of code to execute in order**

```
var res2 = await fetchData(url_2, file_path_2);
await console.log('step one.');
var res1 = await fetchData(url_1, file_path_1);
await console.log('step two.');
```

**However, the actual order of their execution is**

step one.
step two.
........
........

**How can we achieve synchronous execution of these four lines of codes?**

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var async = require("async");

(async() => {

var url_1 = 'https://aaa.bbb.ccc.com';
var url_2 = 'https://library.harvard.edu/';

var file_path_1 = fs.createWriteStream('./intelcenter/aaa.bbb.ccc.txt');
var file_path_2 = fs.createWriteStream('./intelcenter/harvard.txt');

var res2 = await fetchData(url_2, file_path_2);
await console.log('step one.');
var res1 = await fetchData(url_1, file_path_1);
await console.log('step two.');

})();


async function fetchData(url,locpath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    async.retry(request(url).pipe(locpath), function(err, result) {
    resolve(result);
    });   
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous Code

I have added callback function for request module and passing the result via next method.

By Default async.retry will make 5 retry.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");
var async = require("async");

(async () => {
  var url_1 = "https://google.com";
  var url_2 = "https://library.harvard.edu/";

  var file_path_1 = fs.createWriteStream("./intelcenter/aaa.bbb.ccc.txt");
  var file_path_2 = fs.createWriteStream("./intelcenter/harvard.txt");

  var res2 = await fetchData(url_2, file_path_2);
  console.log("step one." + res2);
  var res1 = await fetchData(url_1, file_path_1);
  console.log("step two." + res1);
})();

function fetchData(url, locpath) {
  console.log("inside fetchData");
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    async.retry(
      function(next) {
        request(url, function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          console.log("inside request");
          next(result);
        }).pipe(locpath);
      },
      function(result) {
        resolve(result);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

To know more about [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html).

Synchronous Code without async.retry

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");

(async () => {
  var url_1 = "https://google.com";
  var url_2 = "https://library.harvard.edu/";

  var file_path_1 = fs.createWriteStream("./intelcenter/aaa.bbb.ccc.txt");
  var file_path_2 = fs.createWriteStream("./intelcenter/harvard.txt");

  var res2 = await fetchData(url_2, file_path_2);
  console.log("step one.");
  var res1 = await fetchData(url_1, file_path_1);
  console.log("step two.");
})();

function fetchData(url, locpath) {
  console.log("inside fetchData");
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("got result");
      result=JSON.stringify(result);
      locpath.write(result);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why.

Comment: I have removed async.retry, I am writing the result to the file inside the callback function of request module.

Comment: @Brad I have modified the answer to specifically to this question

Comment: The async api , At first, I don't understand the meaning of apiMethod.,now is replaced by function(next)     async.retry({
  times: 10,
  interval: function(retryCount) {
    return 50 * Math.pow(2, retryCount);
  }
}, apiMethod, function(err, result) {
    // do something with the result
});